# preventing activity to be destroyed when device sleeps

Tags: wear-os

How can I manage to keep my activity in the foreground when I come back from sleeping mode?

I tried this (but it looks like it's only used to prevent the device to sleep)

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "sleep" mode? In a normal situation, your activity goes away and your watch-face takes over. If you don't want the watch-face to take over but want the activity to be in low-powered mode, you can have your activity go into ambient mode by extending WearableActivity and calling setAmbientEnabled() and use the relevant callbacks to stay informed about when your app enters the ambient mode to avoid using excessive CPU, and to resume normal operation when you exit the ambient mode.

Comment: By sleeping, I mean when you put the palm of your hand on the screen. Is there a way when u touch back the screen to have the activity in the foreground?

Comment: As I said, you need to implement ambient mode for your activity. But be mindful of the user's expectations; they like to use their watch as a watch as well so unless it really makes sense for your app to behave that way, let your app go away and a watch face take over so when user glances at his/her watch, they can read off the time!